# Cocos2D - HTML5, button stops working after scaling canvas

Tags: html, canvas, cocos2d-iphone, scaling

On "window resize" I'm scaling canvas to fit the screen.

```
cc.renderContext.translate(0, cc.canvas.height);
cc.renderContext.scale(xScale, xScale);
cc.Director.getInstance().setContentScaleFactor(xScale);
```

Scaling works great but...
I have a button on screen (cc.MenuItemImage) It works until the app is scaled.

Any idea how to keep it working?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug with touches not being scaled appropriately. You can download a patched CCTouchDispatcher from here until it is fixed in the next release hopefully: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/19/topics/31205

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to do this in your own way, in version 2.2.2 cocos2d-html5 proposed a proper refactored resolution policy design.

Basically, you need to add these functions calls:

```
// This makes your canvas resized when browser window resized
cc.EGLView.getInstance().resizeWithBrowserSize(true);

// This makes your canvas adapt to current window size
cc.EGLView.getInstance().setDesignResolutionSize(800, 450, cc.RESOLUTION_POLICY.SHOW_ALL);
```

More detailed documentation is here: http://cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Understand_the_Resolution_Policy_in_Cocos2d-Html5_222